# Scheme :Why am i getting this error -assertion-violation: argument of wrong type [car] (car '())

Tags: error-handling, functional-programming, scheme

my function in scheme is trying to get the province details:

```
(define (getProvincesHelper sales provincesList)

  (if (null? sales) 

      provincesList

      ( getProvincesHelper (cdr sales) (append  (list (cadr(cadddr sales))) provincesList))

  ) 
)

(define (getProvinces sales)

 (getProvincesHelper sales '())

)
```

The list of data is in this format

```
;(orderNum (orderDate shipDate) (grossSale discount profit unitPrice) (deliveryMethod province) product)

(3 ("10/13/2010" "10/20/2010") (261.54 0.04 -213.25 38.94) ("Regular Air" "Nunavut") "Eldon Base for stackable storage shelf, platinum")
```

I get the error:

```
assertion-violation: argument of wrong type [car]
                     (car '())
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
(cadr (cadddr sales))
```

Requires `sales` to have enough structure so that you don't take `car` or `cdr` off a non pair value. This is for every a and d in its name so:

```
(cadr '(1))
```

Makes the same error, `cdr` works, but `car` on `'()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bigger list or tree like structures, you can use `list-ref`. It takes a list and returns the nth element starting with 0.

If you want to get "Nunavut" from your example list, you have to take the 4th element, which is again a list. And the car of the cdr of this element is the result.

Example:

```
;;        (orderNum (orderDate    shipDate)     (grossSale discount profit  unitPrice) (deliveryMethod province)  product)
(let ((l '(3        ("10/13/2010" "10/20/2010") (261.54    0.04     -213.25 38.94)     ("Regular Air"  "Nunavut") "Eldon Base for stackable storage shelf, platinum")))
  (cadr (list-ref l 3)))
```